# TFS - Team-Foundation-Server Synonyms

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[tfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tfs) should be a synonym for [team-foundation-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/team-foundation-server) (or Vice Versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that [team-foundation-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/team-foundation-server) has fewer questions than [tfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tfs) which means an automated synonym won't work. Let me see what I can spin up from the mod tools.

---

All done